# How to access project XML from a Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working on a Visual Studio extension that needs to directly modify a project's msbuild file (e.g. *.csproj). Unfortunately, the [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx) doesn't seem to publicly expose any objects that support this.

If all else fails, I can always create a [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project%28v=vs.121%29.aspx) object based on the file after a save event, make my edits there, then re-save. However, this would force the user to reload their project, which I'd prefer to avoid.

A better partial solution is described in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6314e71-c721-474d-8291-1f0f2eb6f029/can-an-extension-set-msbuild-properties-before-starting-a-project-build?forum=vsx). Visual Studio keeps some of its evaluated objects in [ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.globalprojectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) and smoothly detects any changes that I make via my extension. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for all project types; it works great for C# but the global collection is left empty when I load a C++ project.

Does anyone know of a good, supported way to access the evaluated project objects? Failing that, is there a solution that doesn't involve forcing a project reload?

The extension needs to be compatible with Visual Studio 2013+ but doesn't need to support older versions.